# PowerShell multiple SQL queries, Cannot use Order by in each query

Tags: t-sql, powershell

I'm using PowerShell to run a SQL query consisting of multiple `SELECT DISTINCT` statements.  Using `UNION ALL` to join these results into one result.

I was wondering if it was possible to use `Order By` in each Select statement.

I currently have the following, only showing Monday,Tuesday but it should be easy to follow along for the remaining days.  If I add `ORDER BY` at the last SELECT statement, the results are ordered correctly but taken out of the DayOfWeek sort.

I'm just not sure how to use any of the examples I've found, which use the `()` to create a nested SELECT statement or SubQuery.

-edit, forgot to mention I'm looking to OrderBy the `[RebootTime]` column for each DayOfWeek query.

```psh
$SQLServer = "ServerNameHere"
$SQLDBName = "DBNameHere"
$SqlQuery = @'
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.server AS [Server], dbo.rack AS [Rack], dbo.Environment AS [Environment], dbo.monday AS [RebootTime], dbo.schedule AS [Schedule]
FROM SomeTable
INNER JOIN SubTable
 ON dbo.Item = dbo.SpecID
WHERE dbo.monday = 1
AND (dbo.Environment = 'Prod' OR  dbo.Environment = 'Cert' OR dbo.Environment = 'Test')
AND (dbo.schedule = 'Weekly' OR dbo.schedule = 'SCCM - Weekly' OR dbo.schedule = 'Monthly' OR dbo.schedule = 'SCCM - Monthly')
AND dbo.Group = 'MyGroup'
AND dbo.object = 'Server'
 UNION ALL
SELECT null, null, null, null, null
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tuesday', null, null, null, null
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Server', 'Rack', 'Environment', 'RebootTime', 'Schedule'
 UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.server AS [Server], dbo.rack AS [Rack], dbo.Environment AS [Environment], dbo.tuesday AS [RebootTime], dbo.schedule AS [Schedule]
WHERE dbo.tuesday = 1
AND (dbo.Environment = 'Prod' OR  dbo.Environment = 'Cert' OR dbo.Environment = 'Test')
AND (dbo.schedule = 'Weekly' OR dbo.schedule = 'SCCM - Weekly' OR dbo.schedule = 'Monthly' OR dbo.schedule = 'SCCM - Monthly')
AND dbo.Group = 'MyGroup'
AND dbo.object = 'Server'
'@
 $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
 $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True"
 $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
 $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
 $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
 $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
 $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
 $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
 $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
 $SqlConnection.Close()
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path D:\Scripts\Output.csv
Invoke-Item -Path d:\Scripts\Output.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
SELECT  Sub.[Server] ,
        Sub.[Rack] ,
        Sub.[Environment] ,
        Sub.[RebootTime] ,
        Sub.[Schedule]
FROM    ( SELECT    t.Pr ,
                    t.RN ,
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR, t.Server) AS [Server] ,
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR, t.Rack) AS [Rack] ,
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR, t.Environment) AS [Environment] ,
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR, t.RebootTime) AS [RebootTime] ,
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR, t.Schedule) AS [Schedule]
          FROM      ( SELECT    1 AS Pr ,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY dbo.monday ) AS RN ,
                                dbo.server AS [Server] ,
                                dbo.rack AS [Rack] ,
                                dbo.Environment AS [Environment] ,
                                dbo.monday AS [RebootTime] ,
                                dbo.schedule AS [Schedule]
                      FROM      dbo --table
                      WHERE     dbo.monday = 1
                                AND dbo.Environment IN ( 'Prod', 'Cert',
                                                         'Test' )
                                AND dbo.schedule IN ( 'Weekly',
                                                      'SCCM - Weekly',
                                                      'Monthly',
                                                      'SCCM - Monthly' )
                                AND dbo.[Group] = 'MyGroup'
                                AND dbo.[object] = 'Server'
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT    2 ,
                                0 ,
                                NULL ,
                                NULL ,
                                NULL ,
                                NULL ,
                                NULL
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT    3 ,
                                0 ,
                                'Tuesday' ,
                                NULL ,
                                NULL ,
                                NULL ,
                                NULL
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT    4 ,
                                0 ,
                                'Server' ,
                                'Rack' ,
                                'Environment' ,
                                'RebootTime' ,
                                'Schedule'
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT    5 ,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY dbo.tuesday ) AS RN ,
                                dbo.server AS [Server] ,
                                dbo.rack AS [Rack] ,
                                dbo.Environment AS [Environment] ,
                                dbo.tuesday AS [RebootTime] ,
                                dbo.schedule AS [Schedule]
                      FROM      dbo --table
                      WHERE     dbo.tuesday = 1
                                AND dbo.Environment IN ( 'Prod', 'Cert',
                                                         'Test' )
                                AND dbo.schedule IN ( 'Weekly',
                                                      'SCCM - Weekly',
                                                      'Monthly',
                                                      'SCCM - Monthly' )
                                AND dbo.[Group] = 'MyGroup'
                                AND dbo.[object] = 'Server'
                    ) t
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    0 ,
                    0 ,
                    'Server' ,
                    'Rack' ,
                    'Environment' ,
                    'RebootTime' ,
                    'Schedule'
        ) AS Sub
ORDER BY Sub.Pr ,
        Sub.RN
```

Comment: This returns the following PowerShell error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.`

Comment: @user4317867, post has been updated, try this variant

Comment: I'm having a rough go adapting that answer into my PowerShell Here String.  I edited the question to include the `FROM` and `INNER JOIN` where appropriate.  PowerShell says `Invalid column name 'RebootTime'."` but I'm unsure which RebootTime it's having difficulties with.

Comment: Ugh is it Friday yet :)  I had RebootTime within the `ORDER BY` clause, it worked when I changed it to the column name from the DB.  In this example changed RebootTime to `dbo.monday` and made the second statement Order By `dbo.tuesday`

Comment: And to make things more complicated (Don't you LOVE endlessly changing requirements!) I had to sort by First `dbo.Environment` Then `dbo.Monday` which was as simple as adding `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY dbo.Environment, dbo.Monday ) AS RN ,` and of course incrementing the `SELECT 1` for all the days of week.  Thank you again @Vasily

Comment: Hate to come back to this but I've been asked to add a header row above the first query.  I've tried adding `SELECT 1 as PR , and ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( ORDER BY NULL, NULL ), AS RN` which of course didn't work, I got an error about the `SubQuery` being empty.

Comment: @user4317867 that's fine, when somebody ask to implement additional data into the final query. so, take a look in my updated post, if I understood correctly then it will solve issue with header row.

Comment: When I add `SELECT 0, 0, 'Thursday', Null, Null, Null, Null` line, this line appears under the column headers.  I had to re-arrange the days of the week, making it Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon, Tues, Wed.  Thanks again for the assistance @Vasily